# UBLOX NEO6M checksum checking?

Tags: python

I am reading the serial input from my serial connections and am receiving data input like this.  These are NMEA strings from a UBLOX NEO6M GPS receiver.

```
$GPRMC,202325.00,A,4008.94847,N,11135.48840,W,0.011,,241017,,,D*6F
$GPVTG,,T,,M,0.011,N,0.020,K,D*24
$GPGSA,A,3,18,24,32,51,08,10,15,27,20,14,21,,1.60,0.86,1.35*0A
$GPGSV,4,1,15,04,44,270,32,08,15,319,30,10,57,284,42,13,04,036,*74
$GPGSV,4,2,15,14,08,205,21,15,30,049,43,16,04,259,,18,74,010,41*7C
$GPGSV,4,3,15,20,18,072,28,21,65,114,36,24,22,100,24,27,41,292,41*72
$GPGSV,4,4,15,32,25,204,28,46,39,160,27,51,43,173,42*4D
$GPGLL,4008.94847,N,11135.48840,W,202325.00,A,D*77
```

The last two digits of each line are its checksum.  Starting at the dollar sign and ending before the asterisk is the payload.  The checksum is supposed to be calculated from the payload using this algorithm from the manual:

```
The checksum algorithm used is the 8-Bit Fletcher Algorithm, which is used in the 
TCP standard (RFC 1145).  This algorithm works as follows:
Buffer[N] contains the data over which the checksum is to be calculated.
The two CK_ values are 8-Bit unsigned integers, only! 
If implementing with larger-sized integer values, make sure to 
mask both CK_A and CK_B with 0xFF after both operations in the loop.
After the loop, the two U1 values contain the checksum, 
transmitted at the end of the packet.
```

Here is the code from the manual on how do to it.  I'm not sure what language the code is written in, but it is not python.

```
CK_A = 0, CK_B = 0
For(I=0;I<N;I++)
    {
    CK_A = CK_A + Buffer[I]
    CK_B = CK_B + CK_A
    }
```

Here is my flawed python version of the same thing:

```
                x=0
                ck_a=0
                ck_b=0
                lentemp=len(payloadstr)
                while x < lentemp:
                        ck_a = ck_a + payloadstr[x]
                        ck_b = ck_b + ck_a
                        x+=1
                print('ck_a='+str(ck_a))
                print('ck_b='+str(ck_b))
```

I am getting this error (not surprisingly):

```
ck_a = ck_a + payloadstr[x]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Having said all of that, I know that I have a data type mismatch.  I'm not sure how to make ck_a and ck_b into an 8-bit integer.  Also, I'm not sure how to convert payload[str] into a number.  Are they talking about ASCII values?  Or are they talking about hex someway?

Here's a link to the [manual](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox6_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_%28GPS.G6-SW-10018%29_Public.pdf)

Page 85 is the bit about checksums.

Comment: The documentation you've referenced is referring to the checksum calculation for the UBX protocol, not for NMEA.  If you want to calculate an NMEA checksum, [read the appropriate documentation](https://rietman.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-calculate-the-nmea-checksum/).

Comment: A good sign that you're looking at the wrong thing is the fact that the 8-bit fletcher algorithm generates 16-bit checksums, while the checksums in your data are only 8-bit quantities.

Answer (score 1):

While inelegant, using the [link](https://rietman.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-calculate-the-nmea-checksum/) in @larsks' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920772/ublox-neo6m-checksum-checking#comment80790312_46920772) and what little regex I can muster:

```
stringz = ('$GPRMC,202325.00,A,4008.94847,N,11135.48840,W,0.011,,241017,,,D*6F',
           '$GPVTG,,T,,M,0.011,N,0.020,K,D*24',
           '$GPGSA,A,3,18,24,32,51,08,10,15,27,20,14,21,,1.60,0.86,1.35*0A',
           '$GPGSV,4,1,15,04,44,270,32,08,15,319,30,10,57,284,42,13,04,036,*74',
           '$GPGSV,4,2,15,14,08,205,21,15,30,049,43,16,04,259,,18,74,010,41*7C',
           '$GPGSV,4,3,15,20,18,072,28,21,65,114,36,24,22,100,24,27,41,292,41*72',
           '$GPGSV,4,4,15,32,25,204,28,46,39,160,27,51,43,173,42*4D',
           '$GPGLL,4008.94847,N,11135.48840,W,202325.00,A,D*77')

import re

for s in stringz:

    # https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#matching-characters

    result   = re.search('\$(.*)\*', s) # everything between '$' and '*' (escaped with '\')

    # https://rietman.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-calculate-the-nmea-checksum/
    # see also https://forum.u-blox.com/index.php/14618/python-generate-checksums-validate-coming-serial-interface

    checksum = 0
    for thing in result.group(1):
        checksum = checksum ^ ord(thing)  # Xor

    ck  = hex(0x100 + checksum)[-2:]
    sck = s[-2:].lower()

    print ("{} == {}: {}".format(ck, sck, ck==sck))
```

returns

```
6f == 6f: True
24 == 24: True
0a == 0a: True
74 == 74: True
7c == 7c: True
72 == 72: True
4d == 4d: True
77 == 77: True
```